# After change my BIOS password, does not accept my new password

Tags: bios

I tried to change my bios password, and for new password, I just pressed enter button. (The field was empty), and after I saved my changes and restart the computer, it asked me to enter BIOS password. It does not accept my previous password, nor my new password- which is an empty field and just press enter.

<del>Does anyone have any idea what my new password is?</del>

Does anyone know how I can get in, so that I can change the password?

Comment: Improved question, to be more generic, less localised.

Comment: @richard - While it improved the question, its still localized, to the author's situation.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you reset the BIOS by pulling the battery, it seems you cannot have a blank password, when you do reset it the BIOS won't have a password which appears to be what you wanted anyways.

**There is no possible way for us to know what the password is.**